# Deserializar JSON con Newtonsoft para distintas respuestas

Tags: c#, json

tengo el siguiente problema.
Hago una peticion rest a un servicio, p.e.
http://example.com/api/getuser/7113
la respuesta es así si existe:

```
{ 
  "Id": 7113,
  "Name": "Ted Norris",
  "BirthDate": "1977-05-13T00:00:00",
  "Phone": "488-555-1212",
  "Address": {
  "Street": "123 Main St",
  "City": "San Diego",
  "State": "CA",
  "Zip": "92115"
}
```

y si hay algún error esta otra respuesta

```
{ 
  "IsSuccess": false,
  "Message": "Can not connect to database"
}
```

como puedo deserializar a dos objetos distintos, cual sería la mejor forma de hacerlo.
 Si puede ser Utilizando la libreria Newtonsoft.Json
muchas gracias.

Comment: Si el JSON viene de hacer la petición al servidor, entonces no es el servidor donde tienes que deserializar. ¿Exactamente qué es lo que esperas hacer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias poner cualquiera de los dos objetos JSON en una variable de tipo `JObject`.
De la siguiente forma:

```
string json = @"{
  CPU: 'Intel',
  Drives: [
    'DVD read/writer',
    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
  ]
}";

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Fuente: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm

Luego para acceder a los valores simplemente:

```
var prop = obj["nombre_propiedad"];
if(prop != null){
    // hacer algo aqui
}
```